# Load another esm file if env is NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-browser, es6-modules

In one file I load something directly from a http url. This dose not work in node's...

Currently I have this method working in both node and the browser but it's too much experimental with top level await, So I'm looking for alternative solutions

```js
// ./utilities.js

const WritableStream = globalThis.WritableStream || 
  // works for browsers
  await import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web-streams-polyfill@3/dist/ponyfill.es2018.mjs')
    .then(r => r.WritableStream)
    // fallback for NodeJs
    .catch(() => {
      // Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are
      // supported by the default ESM loader. Received protocol 'https:'
      return import('web-streams-polyfill')
    })
    .then(r => r.WritableStream))
```

What I would like to do is to override `./utilities.js` with `./node-utilities.js` with import maps in `package.json` if possible and load the rest from NPM instead if it's running in NodeJS
I know the web has support for import-maps, but I would like to do it the other way around and do web first and do the mapping (module resolving) on the server side instead.

```
// ./utilities.js
import { WritableStream } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web-streams-polyfill@3/dist/ponyfill.es2018.mjs'
export { WritableStream }
```

```
// ./node-utilities.js
import { WritableStream } from 'web-streams-polyfill'
export { WritableStream }
```

```js
// index.js

// would load ./utilities.js in the browser and `./node-utilities.js` in NodeJS
import { WritableStream } from './utilities.js'
```

---

I do not wish to use `isNode ? import(x) : import(y)` (i could if top level await was more supported, but it's not)

I have tried this

```json
"exports": {
   "./src/utilities.js": "./src/node-utilities.js"
},
```

but still throws  `Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader. Received protocol 'https:'`